# Cannot convert the same properties key in json string to array by PHP json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
<?php
     $array = json_decode('{"image":"9794948495.jpg","image":"9703471814.jpg","image":"9711995133.jpg"}');
     echo json_encode($array,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
?>
```

My code is like that.
And it result just like :

`{"image":"9711995133.jpg"}`

Could you guys help me to have :

```
{"image":"9794948495.jpg","image":"9703471814.jpg","image":"9711995133.jpg"}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You are declaring just a key, in other words declare image as an array

Answer (score 0):

You must declare `image` as an array:

```
{"image":["9794948495.jpg","9703471814.jpg","9711995133.jpg"]}
```

Your format is overwriting each time the `image` key and you end up with the last parsed value :

```
{"image":"9794948495.jpg","image":"9703471814.jpg","image":"9711995133.jpg"}
```

when you will `var_dump` the array you will have:

```
array(1) { ["image"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(14) "9794948495.jpg" [1]=> string(14) "9703471814.jpg" [2]=> string(14) "9711995133.jpg" } }
```

thus the original: `$images = array('image'=>array("9794948495.jpg","9703471814.jpg","9711995133.jpg"));`

Comment: Ya, the problem that i cannot change the format of input. Can i have the output as var_dump